# undefined is not a function after refactor

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I put my code into different modules:

```
.....
var util = require('util');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.perform_flatten = function(event, context) {
     .......
     CONTEXT = context;

   s3_helper.get_object(SRC_BUCKET, SRC_KEY, this.flatten);
};
```

this.flatten is a callback to a module in the same file

```
exports.flatten = function(data){
    .......

 s3.putObject({Bucket: dst_bucket, Key: dst_key, Body: buffer}, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    }else{
      console.log(data);           // successful response
      CONTEXT.done();
    }
  });
}
```

The **code runs perfectly until** it comes to this line `CONTEXT.done();`.

Then I get the error: `undefined is not a function`

**I do not understand why? Especially because I believe I declared CONTEXT as global right?**

I have to call `context.done()` in order to execute a Lambda function on Amazon. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html THANKS

Comment: What is the `typeof` and value of `context` within `perform_flatten`?

Comment: Also, the `context` can be passed to `flatten()` without making it a global using another `function` or [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) -- `this.flatten.bind(this, context)` and `exports.flatten = function(context, data){`.

Comment: Attempting to use a global by assigning to an undeclared variable is considered a very bad practice in nodejs.